2015 Ford Fusion in limp mode
2015 Ford Fusion in limp mode
I recently purchased a 2015 Fusion that had a P0141 O2 sensor error, car ran fine. Then, my daughter was driving it and it went into limp mode. Hooking it up to my code reader, this is what I saw :

Cleared the codes and got it home. Then ran fine.
CAR BACKGROUND
According to the carfax, the car has been wrecked on both the left and right front, on different occasions.
WHAT I’VE DONE SO FAR
Took it to my mechanic. He started it up in the morning, went into LIMP mode again. He cleared codes, drove it 50 miles with no issue.
Got it back, went into limp mode again. For the most part, same errors, with a new P06A7 “Computer and Auxiliary Outputs” error.
Looking at sensor readings while running in limp, noticed MAP sensor was reading 0 PSI. Unhook sensor and reading goes high. Decided to replace MAP. Ran fine, then limp. Thinking it was a bad ground, potentially due to the wrecks, I ran a wire between passenger side and battery. Restarted car and ran fine. Noticed MAP was responding with throttle, etc anywhere from 10PSI to 25PSI. Let it sit for a few minutes restarted, limp again. MAP was back to 0 PSI.
Not sure where to go next. The MAP acting weird makes me think there is a larger, potentially electrical problem.
Thoughts please?

With front end damage to both sides, wiring damage may be hidden and intermittent. If I'm not mistaken, map sensors operate on 5vdc. Many sensors in EFI systems use 5vdc as power. Maybe wiring damage from the main source of 5vdc? You'll need wiring diagrams to chase damaged wiring and intermittent voltages. Measuring for supply voltage to the map sensor, tug/bend/jiggle the wire harness and see if voltage changes drastically. Intermittent shorts to ground is another possibility. Examining the entire under hood wiring, carefully, may be needed to find the problem(s).

I would check for any recalls my friend had a Ford and going to work went into limp mode. I think there was a recall on the throttle body I think good luck.

Thanks. After more research, found small amount of oil in the ECM. not sure if it's wicking up the harness from a failed sensor. Did find oil in the connector for the cam phaser intake sensor. Considering that a smoking gun. Going to replace that.
